# C++ template specialization of function: "illegal use of explicit template arguments"

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, typename

The following template specialization code:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void spec1()
{

}
```

Test case 1:

```
template< typename T1> //compile error
void spec1<int>()
{

}
```

Test case 2:

```
template< typename T2> //compile error
void spec1<int>()
{

}
```

generates the following compilation error:

> error C2768: 'spec1' : illegal use of explicit template arguments

Does anyone know why?

Comment: what platform/compiler are you using?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Function templates cannot be partially specialised, only fully, i.e. like that:

```
template<>
void spec1<char, int>()
{

}
```

For why function templates cannot be partially specialised, you may want to [read this](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

When you specialise partially (only possible for classes), you'd have to do it like that:

```
template <typename T1>
class class1<T1, int>
{

};
```

so you have to list `T1` again.

The way your specialisations are written, they would be ambiguous for `spec1<int, int>`.

Comment: Ah so I can have partially specialized classes embedded with static functions?

Comment: Oh, i see the article you link to explains matters already. I removed my answer, since i found that forwarding to a class is more convenient for this case. In cases where `T1` and `T2` are used as types of the function parameters though, i find overloading much more readable, since it is just like normal function overloading then.

Comment: When I read "only possible for classes", I balked. I found that it's possible for both classes and structs ;-).

Comment: @LimitedAtonement: As classes and structs are pretty much the same thing, I'm ok with "only for classes".