# std::get like (partial) template specialization

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have class for **complex numbers**:

```
template<typename T>
struct Complex{
    T r;
    T i;
};
```

I decided to add function similar to `std::get`:

```
template<int X, typename T>
T get(const Complex<T> &a){
   switch(X){
       case 0: return a.r;
       case 1: return a.i;
   }
}
```

This works OK. Also I know the compiler can optimize it away.

Then I decided to rewrite it in different way:

```
template<int X,typename T>
T get(const Complex<T> &a);

template<typename T>
constexpr T get<0, T>(const Complex<T> &a){
    return a.r;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr T get<1, T>(const Complex<T> &a){
    return a.i;
}
```

However this does not compile and I am curious how correct implementation will be?

I tried to check how `std::get` is made, but I was unable to find anything that was "readable".

Comment: In what kind of context `get<0>(myComplex)` is preferable over `myComplex.r`?

Comment: Is more "standard", also in future, if you do Quaternion class, you will be able to use unified interface. Also educational reason.

Comment: If `std::get` worked with your class, it would be even more standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function templates cannot be partially specialised.

Another method is *tag dispatching* that achieves a similar effect using function overloading:

```
template<int X>
using Int = std::integral_constant<int, X>;

template<typename T> inline T get(const Complex<T> &a, Int<0>) { return a.r; }
template<typename T> inline T get(const Complex<T> &a, Int<1>) { return a.i; }

template<int X, typename T>
inline T get(const Complex<T> &a) { return get(a, Int<X>{}); }
```

Comment: this is my favorite way, how did I forgot for this.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 you can implement this exercise like:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct Complex{
    T r;
    T i;
};


template<int X, typename T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<X == 0,T>::type
get(const Complex<T> &a){
    return a.r;
}

template<int X, typename T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<X == 1,T>::type
get(const Complex<T> &a){
    return a.i;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d6aceb236daee5b)

[Partial template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) is applicable for
class templates, not function templates.

In C++14 you can write trivially more concise code using [`std::enable_if_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

And in C++17 you may use [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) to write a single function template instead of
SFINAE overloads.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with this, but it looks very complex for such an easy task:

```
namespace complex_impl__{
    template<int X, typename T>
    struct GetHelper{
        static T get(const Complex<T> &a);
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct GetHelper<0, T>{
        constexpr static T get(const Complex<T> &a){
            return a.r;
        }
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct GetHelper<1, T>{
        constexpr static T get(const Complex<T> &a){
            return a.i;
        }
    };
}

template<int I,typename T>
constexpr T get(const Complex<T> &a){
    return complex_impl__::GetHelper<I, T>::get(a);
}
```

Then I was able to move `T` into `get()` method, so I can make less code:

```
namespace complex_impl__{
    template<int I>
    struct GetHelper{
        template<typename T>
        static T get(const Complex<T> &a);
    };

    template<>
    struct GetHelper<0>{
        template<typename T>
        constexpr static T get(const Complex<T> &a){
            return a.r;
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct GetHelper<1>{
        template<typename T>
        constexpr static T get(const Complex<T> &a){
            return a.i;
        }
    };
}

template<int I,typename T>
constexpr T get(const Complex<T> &a){
    return complex_impl__::GetHelper<I>::get(a);
}
```

One may "strip" entire `template<int I> struct GetHelper` class:

```
namespace complex_impl__{
    template<int I>
    struct GetHelper;

    template<>
    struct GetHelper<0>{
        template<typename T>
        constexpr static T get(const Complex<T> &a){
            return a.r;
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct GetHelper<1>{
        template<typename T>
        constexpr static T get(const Complex<T> &a){
            return a.i;
        }
    };
}

template<int I,typename T>
constexpr T get(const Complex<T> &a){
    return complex_impl__::GetHelper<I>::get(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't partially specialise function templates. Please read
[C++ template specialisation of function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1416382/6208895) and [Getting “illegal use of explicit template arguments” when doing a pointer partial specialization for a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16154751/6208895), which Nick describes the same solution of.

To get the template specialisation to work, please see Nick's answer.

Your solution does seem fine though,
I would just change the switch into an `if constexpr`.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Complex 
{
    T r;
    T i;
};

template<int X, typename T>
constexpr T get(const Complex<T> &a)
{
    if constexpr(X == 0)
    {
        return a.r;
    }
    else if constexpr (X == 1)
    {
        return a.i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Complex<int> test;
    test.r = 1;
    test.i = 12;

    std::cout << get<0>(test) << std::endl;
    std::cout << get<1>(test) << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();

}
```